# Error when using input.nextDouble in Java

Tags: java, input

I'm a beginner in Java and i'm trying to make a simple BMI Calculator in Java (in metres and kilograms).
I get an error whenever I type my height as a double input:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at ui.BMI_Calculator.main(BMI_Calculator.java:15)
```

Code:

```
package ui;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMI_Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        double height, weight;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Give height (in metres): ");
        height = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf("%nGive weight (in kilograms): ");
        weight = input.nextDouble();


        double BMI = weight / (height * height);

        System.out.printf("%nBMI = %d", BMI);

        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Exactly what input are you providing? Also `%d` is for int formats, you want something with `%f` for a `double`.

Comment: did you provide the double values when running a program?

Comment: I put 1.75 at my input for my height and I got an error

Comment: Better to get a `String` using `Scanner.nextLine()` and then parsing that `String` to `Double` using `Double.parseDouble()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code on an online IDE and it worked, then I tested on my machine and got the same error as you, then I tested again, but using commas (,) instead of dots(.) for the decimal point, and it worked. The **InputMismatchException** is throw because the Scanner object uses the default Locale of the JVM to parse the input value, and when it is different from the expected it causes the exception.

You can pass a locale to the scanner that uses . as a decimal separator:

```
input.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

or just use (,) when entering your values.

Also, there is another error in your code, in the last printf:

```
 System.out.printf("%nBMI = %d", BMI);
```

You should use a %f for floating points instead of a %d, that is used for integers. You can find more about how to format numeric output in the following [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).